# php detect and redirect old links to new one

Tags: php, redirect, http-redirect

recently i have changed the website softare and i have a very big problem with the old links. My website have more than 15.000 indexed page on google and i dont whant lose this links.

my old profile links look like this http://website.com/username

the new links look like this: http://website.com/profile/view/?uid=123469

so, the problem is that my new sistem use Kohana, and all 301 etc, are redirected to 404 page,  on htcacces i cant rewrite, i tryed all methods but nothing, any idea?

Comment: And those 'all methods' are?

Comment: If you use 301 redirects, your page rank will transfer to the target and you'll be fine.  If you already have this live, you are already losing indexed pages.  Just write a script to handle the old URLs.  There isn't some magic that can do it for you, as only you know the format of the old, and how to translate that to the new.

Answer (score 0):

Generate a **flatfile dictionary** and up front, before anycode is launched, run the current request query through the dictionary and do a `header 301` request to the corresponding new address.

```
$url_rewrites = array(
    '/profile/view/?uid=123469' => '/username',
    '/profile/view/?uid=1234692' => '/username2',
    '/profile/view/?uid=1234693' => '/username3',
);

if (($key = array_search($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']), $url_rewrites)){
    header('Location: ' . $key, true, 301);
}
```

After about two or three months, drop the dictionary.